# Why Security Hotspot sonar issues is not appearing in Intellij idea?

Tags: sonarqube

Run "All Tests" with coverage is not showing Security Hotsport issues in the sonar report

Answer (score 0):

Currently SonarLint will not detect Hotspots when analysing code in the IDE.

See this post for more information: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/intellij-sonarlint-security-hotspots/39174